# How can i extract nanosecond from interval day to second in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp, databricks

```
def calculate_session_duration(df):
     newDf = df.groupBy("SessionId").agg((F.max("TimeGenerated") - F.min("TimeGenerated")).alias("TimeRange"))
     return df2
```

Hi guys, i have the following function in PySpark, the subtraction between timestamp returns me an "interval day to seconds" data type.
I'm trying to figure it out how to extract the nanoseconds from the column "Time Range" that is something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJMqw.png)

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def calculate_session_duration(df):
     newDf = df.groupBy("SessionId").agg((F.max("TimeGenerated").cast(DoubleType()) - F.min("TimeGenerated").cast(DoubleType())).alias("TimeRange"))
     return df2
```

The output will be something like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+------------------+             
|x                  |y                         |TimeRange         |
+-------------------+--------------------------+------------------+
|2022-06-10 00:00:00|2022-06-10 17:26:39.438444|62799.438443899155|
+-------------------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

and values after the floating point are fractions of second.